# I am trying to rewrite a function using AVX2 and running into issues

Tags: c++, avx, avx2

Original Scalar function

```
static inline uint32 abc(uint32 bytes, int shift)
{
uint32 kMul= 0x1e35a7bd;
return (bytes * kMul) >> shift;

}
```

Equivalent AVX function

```
 static inline uint32 abc(uint32 bytes, int shift)
    {
    uint32 kMul= 0x1e35a7bd;
     __m256i a,b,c,resShift,shift_256i;
    a=_mm256_set1_epi32(bytes);
    b=_mm256_set1_epi32(kMul);
    shift_256i=_mm256_set1_epi32(shift);
    c=_mm256_mul_epi32(a,b);
    resShift=_mm256_srlv_epi64(c,shift_256i);
   // I am not sure what function to use to convert m256i variable into integer
 }
```

I am not sure how to convert m256i variable into integer in the last step. resShift has the m256i value of the right shift, but i have to convert that into integer form and return from that function. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consult [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/). You clearly need some *extract* intrinsic, but I can't find any to do it in one step. Here is how to do it in two instructions:

```
__m128i lower = _mm256_extracti128_si256(resShift, 0);
return _mm_extract_epi32(lower, 0);
```

Note however, that there is completely no sense in what you are doing. Instead of computing a single result for a single input, you duplicate this input eight times and solve eight equal problems to get eight equal answers. So you do eight times more work without any need. Also, the duplication itself (*set1_* intrinsics) will take additional time. Your AVX routine will not work faster than the scalar one.

P.S. By the way, you should use *_mm256_srlv_epi32* instead of *_mm256_srlv_epi64* for shifting, because you have packed 32-bit data in your registers.

Comment: Extract with an index of zero is a no-op.  Just use the `xmm` reg.  With intrinsics, that means casting it to `__mm128i`.  You don't want the compiler to ever emit `vextracti128 xmm0, ymm1, 0`, because that's just a slow version of `vmovdqua xmm0, xmm1`.  `vextracti128` is *only* useful when the immediate is non-zero.  But +1 for explaining why it's crazy to broadcast a scalar and then do the same op, rather than take a vector of inputs.